# find + how to delete files that exists only on specific folder

Tags: linux, rhel, find, rm

to delete files on under folder we can use the following approach with find

```
find /home -type f -delete
```

but how to delete recursive only the files that exists under temp folder ?

lets say we have the following example of temp path

```
/home/bla/bla/temp
/home/test/temp
/home/subf/subf/subf/temp
.
.
.
/home/1/temp
```

how to change the find syntax in order to delete only the files under `temp` directory

*the target is to use find command in order to match only the temp folders and remove the files under temp directory*

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1729655/432690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  find /home -type f -delete
> ```

Doesn't delete the *files*, it deletes the *regular files* only, to the exception of all other types of files including fifos, devices, directories, symlinks, sockets, etc.

If the intent is to delete all files except those of type *directory*, that is keep just the bare bone directory tree, you'd use `! -type d` in place of `-type f`.

To delete all the non-directory files that are found in or below any directory called `temp`, you'd do:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home -path '*/temp/*' ! -type d -delete
```

Comment: I guess you used `LC_ALL=C` because in some cases it makes some difference and then using `LC_ALL=C` is better than not using it. Can you give an example of such case and such difference?

Comment: I found an explanation in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708631/108618). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could just delete temp folders and recreate them :

```bash
function delete-and-recreate() {
    rm -r $1
    mkdir $1
}

delete-and-recreate $(find . -name temp -type d)
```