# Find directories with name, but filter them if they contain a specific top-level file in them

Tags: bash, shell, find, filter

I want to find all directories that are named `Contents` and then from the list of found results, I want to filter them and only include those that have a file named `Database.json` directly inside them.

```
find / -type d -name Contents 2>/dev/null |
while read dir;
do
    if [ -f $dir/Database.json ]; then
        echo $dir
    fi
done
```

This code works. But I think it's overkill. I think there should be an easier way to do it.

Can I rewrite this code to become simpler?

Comment: have you try something like: `ls **/Contents/Database.json`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `find`, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path '*/Contents/Database.json' -printf '%h\n'
```

Where `%h` gives you the `h`ead of the path, that is the dirname.

`LC_ALL=C` is needed for `*` to match any sequence of bytes regardless of what the user's locale regards as *characters*, as file paths can be made of any sequence of bytes other than 0 which don't have to make up characters in the user's locale.

Similar with `zsh`, also giving you a sorted list, excluding hidden ones, add also reporting symlinks to directories that contain a `Database.json`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/Contents/Database.json(N:h)
```

For a closer equivalent to GNU `find`'s approach:

```
print -rC1 -- **/Contents(NDoN/e['
  [[ -e $REPLY/Database.json || -L $REPLY/Database.json ]]'])
```

Where:

- `D` includes hidden files (`D`ot files)
- `oN` does `N`ot `o`rder the list.
- `/` selects the files of type directory.
- `e['code']` checks that the dirs contain a `Database.json` file of any type including broken sym`L`ink.

In any case, you [cannot post-process the list like you do there](/q/321697). Instead, you'd do:

With GNU `find` and `zsh` or `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -ru3 -d '' file; do
  something with "$file"
done 3< <(LC_ALL=C find . -path '*/Contents/Database.json' -printf '%h\0')
```

With `zsh`:

```
for file (**/Contents/Database.json(N:h)) something with $file
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)